# Rewrite/redirect question regarding extensions and slashes

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to make nice, SEO Friendly URLs from my PHP pages, but I keep running into 500 Internal Errors and so I'm stuck. Here's the rundown:

**Folder Structure**

```
  /    
    /index.php
       /about      <--Folder
       /about/index.php   
       /about/our-people.php   <--a subpage
       /services   <--Another folder
       /services/index.php
       /services/service1.php  <--another subpage
```

I want it to be so that the URLs don't have the .php extension but contain a trailing slash in place. So for instance the "Our People" page would be **www.example.com/about/our-people/**

www.example.com/about/our-people.php or www.example.com/about/our-people (no trailing slash) would go to **www.example.com/about/our-people/**

I know this question has probably been asked to death, but I've tried a lot of the examples out there from both Stackoverflow and other places. Apache is like voodoo to me, sometimes it does magical things, and sometimes it just doesn't work. Here's the code I have so far:

```
#add www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301] 

#Remove .PHP
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

#Add Slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Just a comment; trailing slashes indicate sub-content, and the slash is more often than not the children of the preceding token. If you really mean that the resource you're seeing is our-people, then it probably should be www.example.com/about/our-people and I bet my boots that this trailing slash rewrite is your main culprit.

Comment: Right now, the code above gives me a Internal Server Error when I type www.example.com/about/our-people/ but the page works for both www.example/about/our-people AND www.example/about/our-people.php ...however I don't want it to do that, I want it to go to the first URL!

Comment: :) Yeah, I get that that's what you want, all I'm saying is that perhaps that's not the wisest (nor most semantically significant) thing to do.

Comment: I was reading articles relating to SEO, and they both mentioned to remove the extension and add the slash. Most CMS'es I use rewrite URLs in this fashion, so I wanted to follow suit. In any perspective, is it not a good idea to have 1 canonical URL version which everything goes to (to avoid duplication). I don't know, like I mentioned earlier, URL rewriting is weird to me :/

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this a little differently. If you are not very familiar with Apache, then my recommendation would be that you take as much responsibility away from Apache as you can and set up a "dispatcher" script that decides which PHP file is executed by inspecting the requested URI.

The idea is pretty simple: "redirect" every request to **one** PHP file, and then use that file to determine which file you actually want to execute.

E.g.

http://domain.com/ => index.php?request=

http://domain.com/moo/ => index.php?request=moo/

http://domain.com/moo/1/2/3/4/ => index.php?request=moo/1/2/3/4/

Et cetera

Example:

(This is assuming you have .htaccess and index.php files in your web root)

**.htaccess:**

```
# "Hi Apache, we're going to be rewriting requests now!"
# (You can do all this in Apache configuration files too, of course)
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Ignore *.gif, *.jpg. *.png, *.js, and *.css requests, so those files
# will continue to be served as per usual
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|js|css)$ - [L]

# For the rest, convert the URI into $_GET[ 'request' ]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [QSA] [L]
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php

print "<pre>Request: " . $_GET[ 'request' ] . "\n";

// Dispatcher should be smarter than this -- otherwise you
// will have serious security concerns

$filename = $_GET[ 'request' ] . '.php';

if( file_exists( $filename ) === TRUE )
    require( $filename );
else
    print "Not found: $filename";
```